# How to create this sequence "x-^-1" "x-^-1" "x-^-1" "x-^-1" "x-^-2" "x-^-2" "x-^-2" "x-^-3" "x-^-3" "x-^-4" in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been given:

Use :,seq(),rep()and possibly other commonly-used operators/functions,but NOT c() or any explicit loops to create the following sequences (compound expres-sions are allowed).

I want to create this sequence:

```
"x-^-1" "x-^-1" "x-^-1" "x-^-1" "x-^-2" "x-^-2" "x-^-2" "x-^-3" "x-^-3" "x-^-4"
```

I know I probably should use paste() function but how do I arrange this to make it to have four 1s three 2s, two 3s and one 4. How do I do this? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` and `rep` as -

```
paste0('x-^-', rep(1:4, 4:1))

# [1] "x-^-1" "x-^-1" "x-^-1" "x-^-1" "x-^-2" "x-^-2" "x-^-2"
# [8] "x-^-3" "x-^-3" "x-^-4"
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Could you elaborate what 1:4 and 4:1 does here? I am still a bit confused how it worked. Thanks!

Comment: second argument to rep is how many times to repeat each of the input elements, see `?rep`

Comment: Yes, exactly as @qwr mentioned. Run `1:4` and `4:1` in the console, 1 is repeated 4 times, 2 is repeated 3 times and so on.